# Polygon to polygon spatial join without double counting join features using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-join

I am a new GIS user trying to aggregate local ward-level voting data up to a broader county-level using a [Spatial Join](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm).

Generally a given ward is within only one county, so a `JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE` for the `join_operation` with a sum Merge Rule and `CONTAINS` as the `match_option` should work. The problem is that the ward and county boundaries aren't always coincident, and some wards are partially within two adjacent counties.

In this case a `CONTAINS` Match Option results in undercounting because some wards aren't included anywhere in the `out_feature_class`. I tried using `INTERSECT` as the Match Option instead but this results in some double counting in the Output Feature Class.

Is there a simple way to ensure that a join feature is included in only one target feature?

Perhaps with a "if > 50% of the join feature is within the target feature" or similar expression.

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.

Comment: Have you considered using the [Intersect](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) tool instead and then adding a PERCENTWITHIN field, calculating it, then assign each ward to a county based on the percentage?

Comment: Kirk - that sounds like it would certainly solve the problem. How would I go about setting that up though?